# Get text from the element

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I want to print the text of the **span** element ( Afghanistan ), but when I use the path of the **span** ( `//span[@class=‘mat-option-text’]` ), it prints the text of the **mat-icon** ( *warning* ) as well.

Console:

```
Afghanistan warning
```

Can anyone help how I can print *Afghanistan* only?

[image]

Comment: Please add the line of code you are using that you expect to output the text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute JavaScript:

```
WebElement span = driver.findElement(By.className("mat-option-text"));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String spanText = jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[0].text", span);
```

Comment: I have handled it like this: getText().replace("warning", "")

Answer (score 0):

The text **Afghanistan** is within a *text node*. So to retrieve the text you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the  `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span.mat-option-text")))).toString());
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='mat-option-text']")))).toString());
  ```